# How do I check a variable for a number and an operator in an if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 <html>
<head>
<title> Buttons</title>
<style type="text/css">

.intro{background-color:;}
.duction{background-color:blue;}
.function{background-color:grey;}
.equals{background-color:orange;}
</style>





</head>
<body>
<form name="calculator">
<input type="text"  name="display" length="50" width="100">
<div>
<input type= "button" value="7" class="intro" id="7" onclick="one(7)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="8" class="intro" id="8" onclick="one(8)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="9" class="intro" id="9" onclick="one(9)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="+" class="intro" id="+" onclick="Operate(+)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="-" class="intro" id="-" onclick="Operate(-)"></button>
<div>
<input type= "button" value="4" class="intro" id="4" onclick="one(4)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="5" class="intro" id="5" onclick="one(5)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="6" class="intro" id="6" onclick="one(6)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="x" class="intro" id="x" onclick="Operate(*)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="/" class="intro" id="/" onclick="Operate(/)"></button>
<div>
<input type= "button" value="1" class="intro" id="1" onclick="one(1)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="2" class="intro" id="2" onclick="one(2)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="3" class="intro" id="3" onclick="one(3)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="=" class="intro" id="=" onclick="Evaluate()"></button>
<div>
<input type= "button" value="0" class="intro" id="0" onclick="one(0)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="." class="intro" id="." onclick="one(.)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="c" class="intro" onclick="clearDigit()"></button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\LS\Desktop\QBJS\button.js">



</script>



</body>
</html>

 var timer;
 var object;
 var thing;
 var digit="";
 var result;


 function one(event)
{
  clearTimeout(timer);
   timer=setTimeout(function(){AddDigit(event);},200);

}
```

My Operator buttons(+-/x) pass the operator to "x" and of course my number buttons pass 
numbers to "x". So I am trying to figure out how to check for numbers and operators in the 
the if statement below so that the parameters can be passed to document.calculator.display.value

```
function AddDigit(x)
{
if (x == ????)

 {document.calculator.display.value=x;}
else
   {document.calculator.display.value+=digit + x;}
}



function Evaluate()
{
  result=eval(document.calculator.display.value);
   document.calculator.display.value = result;
}
```

I'm also trying to figure out a way to swap the text between two buttons after they have been "highlighted" with a className change to "duction". (this question is totally unrelated to the first

```
document.ondblclick=function(button)
{
  clearTimeout(timer);

  thing=button.target;

if(thing.className=="intro")
  {thing.className="duction";}

else if(thing.className=="duction")
  {thing.className="intro";}    
}



function clearDigit()
{
  document.calculator.display.value="";
}
```

Comment: This is very confusing. Please provide your HTML and the rest of your Javascript. And split this into two questions - your `className` stuff is unrelated to your first problem.

Answer (score 2):

Some of your id attributes are invalid. Function names starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors.

To test if the argument is a digit:

```
function addDigit(x) {

  if (/^\d$/.test(x)) {
    // x is a single digit
  }
  ...
}
```

#### Edit

Some further explanation. An expression in `/ /` is a [regular expression literal](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.5), which creates a [regular expression (RegExp) object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10). Methods of the object, and the object itself, can be used in various ways.

The pattern `^\d$` matches a string of exactly one digit (0 to 9). The [`test`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.3) method  returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the argument matches the pattern or not. So the expression:

```
/^\d$/.test(x)
```

creates a regular expression object with a pattern to match a single digit, then uses it to test if the supplied argument matches, finally returning boolean `true` or `false`.

You could also use [`String.prototype.match`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.10):

```
x.match(/^\d$/)
```

but that requires `x` to be a string, whereas `test` will convert the argument to a string if it isn't one already. It also returns an array (if at least one match is found) or `null` (if no match is found). So it requires Type conversion to boolean, which isn't as tidy as `test` which returns a boolean to start with.

HTH. :-)

Comment: That is a regular expression, support for which is built in to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two ways to do it (and I'm sure there are more).

```
function AddDigit(x) {
    //if it parses to an integer or is a literal '.'
    if (typeof parseInt(x, 10) === 'number' || x === '.') {
        //digit or decimal
        document.calculator.display.value = x;
    } else {
        //operator: + - x /
        document.calculator.display.value += digit + x;
    }
}

function AddDigit(x) {
    //use a RegExp
    var operator = /[+-x\/]/;
    if (operator.test(x)) {
        //operator: + - x /
        document.calculator.display.value += digit + x;
    } else {
        //digit or decimal
        document.calculator.display.value = x;
    }
}
```